# How send HTTP Request from OrbeonFormController to custom YformService classes?

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, orbeon, sap-commerce-cloud, storefront

I am using Hybris 6.5. I have published yform on storefront.

Now problem is, When I click on submit(save) button for saving form data I want to fetch customer data which is currentlly logged in System but for getting data I need to fetch cookies first.

To fetch cookies I need http request which comes from submitting save button on published form.

Comment: Akshay, we'll need to know more about your situation to be able to help. What does your save/submit do? Does it run a process you defined in your `properties-local.xml`? What is the `OrbeonFormControlller` you refer to in the question title? Is that a class for some code you wrote? How do you retrieve the user information (Java call or REST call, and from where, with what technology)?

Comment: @avernet: The Form is published on our custom storefront(Hybris commerce site).We login from the storefront and fill the survey.What we need here is to get the user information who logged In on storefront(Hybris commerce site).Currently, yforms is not fetching this information to us.reason being they are running as two separate contexts. Would like to know how can we approach to get the user information.

Comment: @vipink. I know the yForms / Orbeon Forms side, but not the Hybris side, so I'm not sure I'll be able to help here. Are you saying that Hybris and Orbeon Forms are running as 2 separate web apps, that users are only logged into Hybris and consequently that Orbeon Forms doesn't know who the current user is?

Comment: @vipink. Have you been able to make some progress on this, and maybe figure if your issue is due to having the 2 separate web apps, where one (Orbeon Forms) doesn't know about users logged into the other (Hybris)?